# Energy method in higher dimensions for waves confusion

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

**Background Information:**

$$\begin{cases}
u_{tt} - \Delta u = f(x,t), \ \ x\in\mathbb{R}^n, t> 0 \\
u(x,0) = g(x)\\
u_t(x,0) = h(x)
\end{cases}$$

Theorem - If $g(x) = h(x) = 0$ for $|x - x_0|\leq t$, and $f(x,t) = 0$ for $(x,t)\in K(x_0,t_0),$ then we have that $u(x_0,t_0) = 0$.

The proof proceeds like this:

We define $$e(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{|x-x_0|\leq t_0 - t}u_t^{2}(x,t) + |\nabla u(x,t)|^2 dx$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{de}{dt} &= \int_{|x-x_0|\leq t_0 - t}u_t u_{tt} + \nabla u \nabla u _t - \frac{1}{2}\int_{|x-x_0| = t_0 - t}u_t^{2} |\Delta u |^2 dS\\
&= \int_{|x-x_0|\leq t_0 - t}(u_t u_{tt} - \Delta u u_t)dx + \int_{|x-x_0| = t_0 - t}(u_t\nabla u\cdot n - \frac{1}{2}u_t^{2} - \frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2)dS
\end{align*}

I don't understand how we go from

$$\int_{|x-x_0|\leq t_0 - t}u_t u_{tt} + \nabla u \nabla u _t - \frac{1}{2}\int_{|x-x_0| = t_0 - t}u_t^{2} |\Delta u |^2 dS$$

to

$$\int_{|x-x_0|\leq t_0 - t}(u_t u_{tt} - \Delta u u_t)dx + \int_{|x-x_0| = t_0 - t}(u_t\nabla u\cdot n - \frac{1}{2}u_t^{2} - \frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2)dS$$

I know this is from Green's theorem but I am not seeing it, specifically how do we get the $-\Delta u u_t$ term? Why is it negative? Also from the $-\frac{1}{2}\int$ part how does it become positive in the next line? Where does the $\frac{1}{2}$ come from?

Please try to explain carefully in detail so that I understand.

Comment: What's $K(x_0,t_0)$?

Comment: @ColinMcQuillan It is not defined in my notes but I believe its the surface of a cone. But knowing what $K(x_0,t_0)$ is not relevant to the question posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product rule for divergences (see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del#Divergence)) gives the identity
$$\nabla \cdot (u_t\nabla u) = \nabla u\cdot \nabla u_t + u_t\Delta u$$
i.e.
$$\nabla u\cdot \nabla u_t = - u_t\Delta u + \nabla \cdot (u_t\nabla u). \tag{*}$$

On the other hand, the divergence theorem gives
$$\int_{|x-x_0|\leq t_0 - t} (\nabla \cdot (u_t\nabla u))dx = \int_{|x-x_0|= t_0 - t} (u_t\nabla u \cdot n)dS.$$

Integrating (*) over $|x-x_0|\leq t_0 - t$ and applying this form of the divergence theorem gives
$$\int_{|x-x_0|\leq t_0 - t}(\nabla u\cdot \nabla u_t)dx =
 - \int_{|x-x_0|\leq t_0 - t}(u_t\Delta u)dx +
\int_{|x-x_0|= t_0 - t}(u_t\nabla u \cdot n)dS.$$

Correcting the typos in the expression for $de/dt$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{de}{dt} &= \int_{|x-x_0|\leq t_0 - t}(u_t u_{tt} + \nabla u \cdot\nabla u _t)dx - \frac{1}{2}\int_{|x-x_0| = t_0 - t}(u_t^{2} +|\nabla u |^2) dS\\
 &= \int_{|x-x_0|\leq t_0 - t}(u_t u_{tt} + \nabla u \cdot\nabla u _t)dx + \int_{|x-x_0| = t_0 - t}(-\frac{1}{2}u_t^{2} -\frac{1}{2}|\nabla u |^2) dS\\
&= \int_{|x-x_0|\leq t_0 - t}(u_t u_{tt} - u_t\Delta u)dx + \int_{|x-x_0| = t_0 - t}(u_t\nabla u\cdot n - \frac{1}{2}u_t^{2} - \frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2)dS.
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't see how $\nabla u \cdot \nabla u_t = -u_t\Delta u + \nabla\cdot(u_t \nabla u)$ can you clarify?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1: can I assume the rule $\nabla \cdot ( \psi \mathbf{A} ) = \psi\ ( \nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}) \ +\  \mathbf{A}\cdot (\nabla \psi) $?

Comment: Yes, I assume $\psi$ is a scalar.

Comment: I've added some clarification of that line.

Comment: I understand your first point now. But going to the integral part I am lost again on every line

Comment: From the second line to the third line, before we found that $\nabla u \nabla u_t = -u_t\Delta u + \nabla\cdot(u_t\nabla u)$ then we from the second to the third line we just have $-u_t \Delta u$ what happened to $\nabla\cdot(u_t\nabla u)$?

Comment: I'm applying the divergence theorem to that term.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63294/discussion-between-dap-and-wolfgang-1).